# Passing the Account Id to Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a parent object `Contract__c`, which has a lookup field to `Account`. 
I have a list button on the `Risk__c` related list on the `Contract__c` object, which opens a Visualforce page.
Currently I am only displaying the Account lookup on my Visualforce page, but this field should really be prepopulated with the Account field on `Contract__c`.

`<apex:inputfield value="{!Risk__c.Account__c}" required="true"/>`

How would I do that?
Tia.

Comment: Have you tried `{!Risk__c.Contract__r.Account__c}`?

Comment: Is the end user supposed to be able to change the value? Do you have a controller/extension?

Comment: I have a controller extension for `Risk__c`, and no, the user doesn't need to be able to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `outputField` instead, as users should not be able to edit this value. You will then need to overwrite the save method, however.

On the Page:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!Risk__c.Contract__r.Account__c}" />
```

In the Extension:

```
public with sharing class RiskExtension
{
    final ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public RiskExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public PageReference save()
    {
        // you could also store this as a property if you wish to populate more fields
        Risk__c risk = (Risk__c)controller.getRecord();
        risk.Account__c = risk.Contract__r.Account__c;
        try
        {
            insert risk;
        }
        catch (DmlException dmx)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(dmx);
            return null;
        }
        return controller.view();
    }
}
```